# HttpRequest from app engine endpoint. Connection reset

Tags: java, http, inputstream, outputstream

I am trying to send an HTTP request from an APP Engine endpoint, from experiments on Postman I know the result is quite big, and the the request usually takes about a minute.

here is my Code:

```
void testRequest() {
    String test = getConnectionString();
    URL url = new URL(YARDI_URL);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    connection.setConnectTimeout(1000000);
    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(os);
    p.print(test);
    p.close();

    YardiResponse response = new 
    YardiResponse(connection.getInputStream().toString());

    System.out.println(response.getResponse());
    connection.disconnect();
}
```

I am getting two errors,

the first is: `java.net.ProtocolException: Cannot write output after reading input.`

and after a long time I am getting a `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` message.

Obviously I am mishandling the steams, and the way I send them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I higly recomend [http-request](https://github.com/jsunsoftware/http-request) built on apache http api.

```
private static final HttpRequest<String.class> HTTP_REQUEST = 
      HttpRequestBuilder.createPost(YARDI_URL, String.class)
           .responseDeserializer(ResponseDeserializer.ignorableDeserializer())
           .contentTypeOfBody(ContentType.TEXT_XML)
           .connectTimeout(someIntValue)
           .socketTimeOut(someIntValue)
           .connectionRequestTimeout(someIntValue).
           .build();

void testRequest() {
   ResponseHadler<String> yardiHandler = HTTP_REQUEST.executeWithBody(yourXml);

   int statusCode = yardiHandler.getStatusCode();
   String content = yardiHandler.get(); //returns response body as String in this case
}
```

Note: I recomend see javadocs of `connectTimeout`, `socketTimeOut` and `connectionRequestTimeout` methods.